# No module named 'blosc.blosc_extension' when importing radio

Tags: module, named

I created an environment (radIOenv) in Anaconda. 
And I typed `python -m pip install git+https://github.com/analysiscenter/radio.git`.

When i type `import radio` or `from radio import CTImagesBatch` I get the following error : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blosc.blosc_extension'`

How can I solve this problem  ?

Here is the full output :

```
(radIOenv) C:\Users\user>python -m pip install git+https://github.com/analysiscenter/radio.git

Collecting git+https://github.com/analysiscenter/radio.git

  Cloning https://github.com/analysiscenter/radio.git to c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-4ii04ktu
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): radio==0.1.0 from git+https://github.com/analysiscenter/radio.git in c:\users\user\anaconda3\envs\radioenv\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10 in c:\users\user\anaconda3\envs\radioenv\lib\site-packages (from radio==0.1.0) (1.16.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.21.0 in c:\users\user\anaconda3\envs\radioenv\lib\site-packages (from radio==0.1.0) (0.24.1)
...

Successfully built radio

(radIOenv) C:\Users\user>python
Python 3.7.1 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 26 2019, 04:46:14) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import radio

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\radIOenv\lib\site-packages\radio\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .preprocessing import *
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\radIOenv\lib\site-packages\radio\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .ct_batch import CTImagesBatch
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\radIOenv\lib\site-packages\radio\preprocessing\ct_batch.py", line 15, in <module>
    import blosc
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\radIOenv\lib\site-packages\blosc\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from blosc.blosc_extension import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blosc.blosc_extension'

>>> from radio import CTImagesBatch

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\radIOenv\lib\site-packages\radio\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .preprocessing import *
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\radIOenv\lib\site-packages\radio\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .ct_batch import CTImagesBatch
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\radIOenv\lib\site-packages\radio\preprocessing\ct_batch.py", line 15, in <module>
    import blosc
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\radIOenv\lib\site-packages\blosc\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from blosc.blosc_extension import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blosc.blosc_extension'
```

Comment: Also when i type print(sys.path)  
['C:\\Users\\user', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\radIOenv\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\radIOenv\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\radIOenv\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\radIOenv', '', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\radIOenv\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\radIOenv\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\user\\.ipython']

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include additional information instead of adding it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I've had an issue in Anaconda before where I've accidentally installed the C version of Blosc rather than the Python version.  I doubt this is your issue but the Python version is installed with `conda install -c conda-forge python-blosc`